# Ajax isn't working properly with my PHP script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am programming in HTML5, PHP and JavaScript. I am trying to use Ajax to do this: when I select one option on `#productoSeleccionado` appear the sizes of this products that is `#tallaSeleccionada` but I think that this code it's no fine. I believe that the code of function and call to data base it's fine.

I have imported the library jQuery-ajax. `productoSeleccionado` works good but when I select one of the options don't appear nothing in the select of `tallaSeleccionada`. I don't know how to put it.

```
<p>
<h3>Seleccione producto:</h3>
<select id="productoSeleccionado" name="producto">
    <?php foreach ($productos as $producto) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $producto["OID_P"]; ?>">
        <?php echo $producto["CODIGO"] . "- " . $producto["CONCEPTO"]; ?>
        </option><?php } ?>
</select>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#productoSeleccionado").on("option", function () {
        $.get("gestionar_Selects.php", {
                productoSeleccionado: $('#productoSeleccionado').val()
            },
            function (data) {
                $("#tallaSeleccionada").empty();
                $("#tallaSeleccionada").append(data);
            }
        );

    });
</script>

<p>
<h3>Seleccione talla:</h3>
<select id="tallaSeleccionada" name="talla"></select>
</p>
```

This code I think that is good is *gestionar_Selects.php*

```
<?php
function listarTallas($conexion, $productoSeleccionado)
{
    try {
        //Puedo poner en vez de * NOMBRE_TALLA probado
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM ASOC_LOCAL_PRODUCTO LEFT JOIN PRODUCTOS ON (ASOC_LOCAL_PRODUCTO.OID_P = PRODUCTOS.OID_P)'
            . 'LEFT JOIN TALLAS ON (ASOC_LOCAL_PRODUCTO.OID_T = TALLAS.OID_T)  LEFT JOIN LOCALIZACIONES ON (ASOC_LOCAL_PRODUCTO.OID_L = LOCALIZACIONES.OID_L) '
            . ' WHERE PRODUCTO.OID_P =:W_OID_P ORDER BY STOCK_MINIMO');
        $stmt->bindParam(':W_OID_P', $productoSeleccionado);
        $stmt->execute();
        return "";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}


if (isset($_GET["producto"])) {

    $conexion = crear_conexionBD()();
    $resultado = listarTallas($conexion, $_GET["producto"]);
    if ($resultado != NULL) {
        foreach ($resultado as $talla) {
            echo "<option value= "$talla["OID_T"]" > $talla["NOMBRE_TALLA"]</option>";
       }
    }
    cerrar_conexionBD()($conexion);
    unset($_GET["producto"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Try `$("#productoSeleccionado").on("change"`

Comment: don't work but thank you

Comment: are you using `PDO`?

Comment: yes I am using PDO

Comment: you need to use `$("#productoSeleccionado").on("change"` and in your `PHP` you are checking for `if(isset($_GET["producto"]))` but in `$.get` you are sending `{ productoSeleccionado: ` this won't work.

Comment: I have put  $("#productoSeleccionado").on("change" and  if(isset($_GET["productoSeleccionado"])) but dont work

Comment: You have other errors, i'll post an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Javascript to use `on('change')`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#productoSeleccionado").on('change', function () {
        $.get("gestionar_Selects.php", {productoSeleccionado: $('#productoSeleccionado').val()}, function (data) {
                $("#tallaSeleccionada").empty();
                $("#tallaSeleccionada").append(data);
            }
        );

    });
</script>
```

In your `PHP`

```
<?php
function listarTallas($conexion, $productoSeleccionado)
{
    try {
        //Puedo poner en vez de * NOMBRE_TALLA probado
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM ASOC_LOCAL_PRODUCTO LEFT JOIN PRODUCTOS ON (ASOC_LOCAL_PRODUCTO.OID_P = PRODUCTOS.OID_P)'
            . 'LEFT JOIN TALLAS ON (ASOC_LOCAL_PRODUCTO.OID_T = TALLAS.OID_T)  LEFT JOIN LOCALIZACIONES ON (ASOC_LOCAL_PRODUCTO.OID_L = LOCALIZACIONES.OID_L) '
            . ' WHERE PRODUCTO.OID_P =:W_OID_P ORDER BY STOCK_MINIMO');
        $stmt->bindParam(':W_OID_P', $productoSeleccionado);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // get rows from DB
        return $rows;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}


if (isset($_GET["productoSeleccionado"])) {

    $conexion = crear_conexionBD()();
    $resultado = listarTallas($conexion, $_GET["productoSeleccionado"]);
    if ($resultado != NULL) {
        foreach ($resultado as $talla) {
            echo '<option value="' . $talla["OID_T"] . '" > ' . $talla['NOMBRE_TALLA'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    cerrar_conexionBD()($conexion); 
    unset($_GET["productoSeleccionado"]);
}
?>
```